# Matrix multiplication with threads C

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix

I am trying to multiply the given matrices and save the result in a global matrix by using multithreading. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct mat_size {
    int row;
    int column;
};
struct mat_values {
    int * m_1;
    int * m_2;
    int i;
    int j;
};
int * result_matrix;
struct mat_size * result_size;
void * matrix_row_result(void * input) {
    struct mat_values *indicators = (struct mat_values *)input;
    int i = indicators->i;
    int j = indicators->j;
    int *m_1 = indicators->m_1;
    int *m_2 = indicators->m_2;

    int result = 0;
    int it = i;

    for(; it < result_size->column; it++)
    {
        printf("%d += %d * %d, ", result, *(m_1 + i * result_size->column + it), *(m_2 + it * result_size->column + j));
        result += *(m_1 + i*result_size->column + it) * *(m_2 + it*result_size->column + j);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    *(result_matrix + i * result_size->column + j) = result;
    // printf("%d ", *(result_matrix + i * result_size->column + j));
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void parallel_matrix_mult(int * m_1, int * m_2, int m, int n) {
    pthread_t * threads;

    result_size = (struct mat_size *)malloc(sizeof(struct mat_size));

    result_size->row = m;
    result_size->column = n;

    int number_threads = (result_size->row) * (result_size->column);
    printf("Creating %d threads and allocating %d size for final matrix\n", number_threads, number_threads * sizeof(int));
    result_matrix = calloc(m * n, sizeof(int));

    threads = (pthread_t *)calloc(number_threads, sizeof(pthread_t));
    int curr_thread = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < result_size->row; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < result_size->column; j++) {
            printf("Allocating %d, %d to thread %d\n", i, j, curr_thread);
            struct mat_values *m_values = (struct mat_values *)malloc(sizeof(struct mat_values));
            m_values->m_1 = m_1;
            m_values->m_2 = m_2;
            m_values->i = i;
            m_values->j = j;
            int status = pthread_create((threads + curr_thread), NULL, matrix_row_result, m_values);
            printf("%d Status for thread %d\n", status, curr_thread);
            pthread_join(*(threads + curr_thread), 0);
            free(m_values);
            ++curr_thread;
        }
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < result_size->row; i++)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        for(size_t j = 0; j < result_size->column; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(result_matrix + i * result_size->column + j));
        }

    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(result_size);
    free(result_matrix);
    free(threads);
}

int main() {
    int matrix_1[4][2] = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
        {5, 6},
        {7, 8}};
    int matrix_2[2][2] = {
        {1, 1},
        {1, 1}};
    int m = sizeof(matrix_1) / sizeof(matrix_1[0]);
    int n = sizeof(matrix_2[0]) / sizeof(int);
    printf("Rows: %d and Columns: %d\n", m, n);
    parallel_matrix_mult((int *)matrix_1, (int *)matrix_2, m,  n);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem seems to be my lack of multithreading understanding. I want for each thread to execute the operation between the i-th row of matrix one and the j-th column of matrix two. A sample code without threading is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int matrix_1[4][2] = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
        {5, 6},
        {7, 8}
    };
    int matrix_2[2][2] = {
        {1, 1},
        {1, 1}
    };
    int * result_matrix;
    int * m = (int *) matrix_1;
    int * m2 = (int * ) matrix_2;

    result_matrix = (int * ) calloc(4 * 2, sizeof(int));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {   
        putchar('\n');
        for(size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            for(size_t x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
                *(result_matrix + i * 2 + j) += *(m + i * 2 + x) * *(m2 + x * 2 + j);
            }
            printf("%d ", *(result_matrix + i * 2 + j));
        }
    }
    free(result_matrix);
}
```

Now the problem is that when I run the sequential code it outputs:

```
3 3 
7 7 
11 11 
15 15
```

as expected; on the other hand, the concurrent program this is the result

```
3 3 
4 4 
0 0 
0 0
```

Here are some debugging messages that I've been using:

```
Rows: 4 and Columns: 2
Creating 8 threads and allocating 32 size for final matrix
Allocating 0, 0 to thread 0
0 Status for thread 0
0 += 1 * 1, 1 += 2 * 1, 
Allocating 0, 1 to thread 1
0 Status for thread 1
0 += 1 * 1, 1 += 2 * 1, 
Allocating 1, 0 to thread 2
0 Status for thread 2
0 += 4 * 1, 
Allocating 1, 1 to thread 3
0 Status for thread 3
0 += 4 * 1, 
Allocating 2, 0 to thread 4
0 Status for thread 4

Allocating 2, 1 to thread 5
0 Status for thread 5

Allocating 3, 0 to thread 6
0 Status for thread 6

Allocating 3, 1 to thread 7
0 Status for thread 7
```

Comment: You do `pthread_create` immediately followed by `pthread_join`. That makes it all serial. Use two loops: one to start the threads, and a second to join the threads.

Comment: Thanks I've made the change  @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

For each result you want to generate you need 2 multiplication and one add. Like

```
result = matrix_1[3][0] * matrix_2[0][0] + matrix_1[3][1] * matrix_2[0][1];
```

but that is not what your code is doing.

Take a look at this:

```
int it = i;

for(; it < result_size->column; it++)
{
    printf("%d += %d * %d, ", result, *(m_1 + i * result_size->column + it), *(m_2 + it * result_size->column + j));
    result += *(m_1 + i*result_size->column + it) * *(m_2 + it*result_size->column + j);
}
```

The value of `result_size->column` is always 2. However, the value of `i` and thereby the value of `it` follows the row number (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3).

So it is only the first two threads that executes the loop twice. The other threads doesn't and consequently the result is wrong.

This can also be seen from your debug printing:

```
0 Status for thread 0
0 += 1 * 1, 1 += 2 * 1,          // Two loops
Allocating 0, 1 to thread 1
0 Status for thread 1
0 += 1 * 1, 1 += 2 * 1,          // Two loops 
Allocating 1, 0 to thread 2
0 Status for thread 2
0 += 4 * 1,                      // One loops
Allocating 1, 1 to thread 3
0 Status for thread 3
0 += 4 * 1,                      // One loops 
Allocating 2, 0 to thread 4
0 Status for thread 4
                                 // No loops
Allocating 2, 1 to thread 5
0 Status for thread 5
                                 // No loops
```

So you need to re-think your algorithm.

BTW: A tip... start by making the function `matrix_row_result` work **without** use of threads. Then when is works in sequential mode you can add the threading part. In other words - doing "create" followed by "join - like:

```
        int status = pthread_create((threads + curr_thread), NULL, matrix_row_result, m_values);
        pthread_join(*(threads + curr_thread), 0);
```

is just fine while debugging the function. When it works you move the join out of the loop.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks